# 2 errors appear when I want to use Hyper CLI

Tags: python, hyperterminal

I currently have a silly problem, because I wanted to switch from Iterm to Hyper, which seems interesting to me with plugins.

PS: I'm on mac M1

However, when I try to run hyper i... I get these 2 stupid errors:
/opt/homebrew/bin/hyper: line 4: /usr/bin/python: No such file or directory
/opt/homebrew/bin/hyper: line 8: ./MacOS/Hyper: No such file or directory

For python, it is installed, except that it is called python3 and not python, the problem is that thanks to SIP, I can't create from simlink which is called 'python'.

For the second error, I don't know what it is.

Thanks in advance to anyone

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. It turned out my path to python is /usr/bin/python3 and I changed that in /opt/homebrew/bin/hyper: line 4